# Из под топота копыт

Tags: грамотная-речь

Илья Сельвинский — автор оборота из известной песни. Что за конструкция, как сохранилась и не подверглась редакции? Написанное пером не вырубить топором?

П.С. Родной ли язык {русский} для И.С. — неважно. Главное в том, что владеет он им не настолько свободно, чтобы не вызывать вопросы. Вот его *К ВОПРОСУ О РУССКОЙ РЕЧИ* — тому пример. Хорошо, что остаётся на бумаге и не звучит под гармошку:

Я говорю: «пошел», «бродил», А ты: «пошла», «бродила».

И вдруг как будто веяньем крыл Меня осенило!

С тех пор прийти в себя не могу... Всё правильно, конечно,

Но этим «ла» ты на каждом шагу Подчеркивала: «Я — женщина!»

Мы, помню, вместе шли тогда До самого вокзала,

И ты без малейшей краски стыда Опять: «пошла», «сказала».

Идешь, с наивностью чистоты По-женски всё спрягая.

И показалось мне, что ты — Как статуя — нагая.

Ты лепетала. Рядом шла. Смеялась и дышала.

А я... я слышал только: «ла», «Аяла», «ала», «яла»...

И я влюбился в глаголы твои, А с ними в косы, плечи!

Как вы поймете без любви Всю прелесть русской речи?

Comment: В чем вопрос-то?

Answer (score 1):

Боюсь, это не поэт недостаточно свободно владеет русским языком, а автор вопроса недостаточно свободно владеет языком поэзии — который, по определению, весьма расширительно трактует языковую норму. Конечно, текст песни — это поэзия прикладная, недалеко ушедшая от рифмованных политических и рекламных лозунгов (речь идёт о текстах, которые специально пишутся для песен — зачастую в сотрудничестве с композитором или на уже готовую музыку). Тем не менее, когда к прикладной поэзии обращается достаточно крупный автор (каким, безусловно, был Сельвинский — хотя и на фоне общего падения русской поэтической культуры 1930-50-х гг., показанного М. Л. Гаспаровым даже и статистически), он спорадически использует весь арсенал поэтических средств, имеющийся в его распоряжении. «Из-под топота копыт» — абсолютно правомерная в поэтической речи конструкция, поскольку поэтическая речь деформирует грамматическую и синтаксическую норму в тех или иных эстетических целях. Нормативно было бы «из-под копыт», с чисто пространственным значением. Замещая сами копыта их топотом, поэт, с одной стороны, акцентирует звукоподражательный момент (в этом он, впрочем, не оригинален, поскольку скороговорка «От топота копыт пыль по полю летит» уже построена таким образом), а с другой — как раз таки придаёт звуковому явлению пространственную семантику (семантический перенос, широко представленный и в языковой норме: ведь когда мы говорим, что звук, хоть бы и копыт, «стелется» или «плывёт» над землёй, мы тоже мыслим звук как локализованный в пространстве). Короче говоря: всё у Сельвинского правильно.

Comment: Правильное легко принимается и благодарно подхватывается. Хорошо бы тому примеры видеть от достаточно свободно владеющего языком поэзии.

Answer (score 0):

В смысле "из-под" без дефиса? Так это на разных сайтах разные ошибки... Написано в 1942 году, и кто его разберёт, что там до Розенталя было.

**Черноглазая казачка**

> Слова И. Сельвинского
>   Музыка М. Блантера

```
Черноглазая казачка
Подковала мне коня.
Серебро с меня спросила,
Труд недорого ценя.
«Как зовут тебя, молодка?»
А молодка говорит:
«Имя ты мое услышишь
Из-под топота копыт!»

Я по улице поехал,
По дороге поскакал.
По тропинке между бурых,
Между серых, между скал.
Маша, Даша,Ира, Зина...
Все как будто не она!
«Катя, Катя» - высекают
Мне подковы скакуна.
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Галина, автору не нравится именно "услышишь из-под топота". ))

Comment: Niemand, приходи, развей тему! Я не заметила абсурда - глуха к плохим стихам. Для Сельвинского русский - неродной. Что, конечно, ни о чём не говорит.

Comment: Что за ерунда, почему неродной? Кстати, Розенталю русский тоже не родной.

Answer (score 0):

Из словаря:  ТОПОТ, Шум, стук, производимый ударами ног при ходьбе, беге, танце и т.п. Конский т. Т. ног, копыт, подков.

В радиотехнике существует профессиональный термин: вытащить из под шума. Допустим есть радиоканал. Радиоканал принимает сигнал. Прием ведется на уровне шума радиоканала и ниже. Задача: Обнаружить наличие полезного сигнала.Выделить и измерить его уровень.

В нашем случае герой "слышит" имя из-под топота копыт, то есть выделяет его из-под шума.

**Примечание**

Наверное, И. Сельвинский (1899 - 1968) "был знаком с радиотехникой". Кстати, он был фактическим лидером группы конструктивистов. "Название течения восходит к конструктивистским течениям начала 1920-х годов в изобразительном искусстве и архитектуре.  Утверждая господствующую роль техники в современной жизни, конструктивисты считали, что произведение искусства должно отвечать всем требованиям технической конструкции с максимальным функциональным использованием каждой из его частей".

Comment: Профессиональных терминов много, но не многие в речь вошли. Может быть и есть случаи сочетания предлога «из-под» со словами, означающими некий звук: стук, треск, скрип, крик... Хотелось бы узнать.

Comment: Sibylla, я знаю этот термин.  Отсылка Ваша к нему весьма сомнительная здесь. Он совершенно другое значит. А так - да, автор владел языком не хуже топикстартера как минимум.

Answer (score 0):

Здесь *из-под* означает примерно то же, что "достать из-под гнета", "из-под завала". Только гнет - образный, звуковой.  Употребление такое, конечно, никакими правилами не предписывается, но поэтически безупречно.
Звук давит, мешает слышать. А имя сквозь него все равно слышно. Как-то так.

Не знаю, правда, насколько это соответствует авторской задумке, дальнейший текст оставляет сомнения. Там получается, что чеканный топот не только не мешает, но, наоборот, выбивает это имя. Но это уже другой вопрос.